What happens if additional BTC is sent to a source address after setting a specific transaction output?
Let's say you are collecting BTC from multiple addresses and sending it to one particular address. For example, you have 3 addresses:
Address A: 1 BTC
Address B: 2 BTC
Address C: 1 BTC
You want to send all the BTC to Address D, so you would expect to send 4 BTC minus the transaction fee. You don't need a change address since you want to collect all the BTC and then move it to some exchange.
Now, let's say you instruct the blockchain to send 3.9 BTC to Address D and leave 0.1 BTC for the transaction fee.(only example fee for ilustration purpose)
Question:
If someone accidentally sends 0.5 BTC to Address A before the transaction is initiated, will the entire remaining balance (0.5 BTC) be used as a fee for the miner or it will remain there or will the transaction be rejected? Or what would happen to this additional BTC?

No the additional amount won't be included in the transaction.
The transaction inputs are not addresses but references to specific unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs) of the earlier transactions that paid money to your addresses A, B and C.
Each address can be associated with many UTXOs and it is only the specifically referenced UTXOs that are used.
